# React useState causes if-else to work incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am trying to set a value using a `useState` hook (React JS) in an `if-else` conditional statement.

I need to check whether there is `addOnName` (which is passed as a parameter), in the `addOnContainer` array and if it does, I need to deduct the `addOnPrice` (which is also passed as a parameter) to the `totalprice` using the `setTotalPrice` (`useState` hook).

If the `addOnContainer` does not include the `addOnName`, I have to add the `addOnPrice` to the `totalprice`.

The code works fine, as it gives me correct outputs in the chrome console. But when I try to use the `useState` hook to set total price, **only the if block runs**, and the `else` never runs no matter what the condition is.

I have tried moving the `useState` out of the `if-else`, and had no luck with that.

What am I doing wrong here? Note that this function is set to be executed when a checkbox is clicked.

```
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(200)

function selectAddOn(addOnName, addOnPrice) {
  let temp = totalPrice

  if (!addOnContainer.includes(addOnName)) {
    temp = totalPrice + addOnPrice

    setTotalPrice(temp)
  } else {
    //never reaches even if the condition is false when useState is used.

    temp = totalPrice - addOnPrice

    setTotalPrice(temp)
  }
}
```

Comment: *"never reaches even if the condition is false"*: Try and let us know if it reaches `else` block when you write : `if (false) {`.

Comment: @AjeetShah no it does not. Still gives the same result if it is used with the setTotalPrice, and gives correct results if setTotalPrice is removed.

Comment: is there any useEffect which have dependency as totalPrice and does to change addOnContainer array?

Comment: Reproduced @AjeetShah : https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-surf-jr55c

Comment: @PriyankKachhela no, the useEffect does not contain any dependencies.

Comment: It is because you are trying to push 'cheese' to addOnContainer and then setState re-render the function wiping out the previous value of addOnContainer. Try using useState for addOnContainer as well and instead of pushing the values into the array create a new array and pass in the old values and then append a new one. This will manage the immutability of the state.

Comment: can you show us how you are initializing `addOnContainer` because in yout codesandbox example it will always be false after each render.

Comment: What will be the most effective workaround for this? @AjeetShah

Comment: @VidarshanAdithya here is the solution that I have added with change in codesandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hofstadter-mnk3z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @UjwalAgrawal applied this to the real use case, solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each rerender, `let addOnContainer = [];` is getting reset to empty array.

You can use a `useRef` to avoid it:

```js
const {useState, useRef} = React

function App() {

  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(200);
  const addOnContainer = useRef([]);
  // let addOnContainer = []; // This was the ISSUE

  function addToTotalPrice (addOnName, addOnPrice) {

    let temp = totalPrice;
    if(!addOnContainer.current.includes(addOnName)){
      addOnContainer.current.push(addOnName);
      temp = totalPrice + addOnPrice;
      setTotalPrice(temp)
    } else {
      temp = totalPrice - addOnPrice;
      setTotalPrice(temp);
    }
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={()=>addToTotalPrice('cheese',30)}>Click, totalPrice: {totalPrice}</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `addOnContainer` should probably be a state atom, though, to have it eventually affect rendering.

Comment: @AKX If we are showing (rendering) `addOnContainer` at UI, then yes, it should be in React State.